# Is there something to replace ng1 string format with ng8?

Tags: angular, angular8, string-interpolation

I have an array of errors to display in a

```
<div *ngFor="let error of arrayOfErrors">
  {{error.errMsg}}
</div>
```

and in AngularJs it was possible to do something in a loop to custom the errMsg like :

```
error.errMsg = 'my error has this code <b><a href="/#/my-link/{0}">{0}/a></b>.'.format(error.errCode);
```

But now, with Angular8, I didn't found any way to simply do this html formatting and interpolation...
I tried something like :

```
error.errMsg = `my error has this code <b><a href="/#/my-link/${error.errCode}">${error.errCode}/a></b>.`;
```

but the html tag aren't interpreted and are displayed like gross string !

I read a lot of topic about Dynamic Component with Angular2+ but it seems to be a bit overkill for my needs ...

Is there a way to simply reach my goal ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using innerHTML

```
 <div *ngFor="let error of arrayOfErrors">
      <span [innerHTML]="error.errMsg"></span>
    </div>
```

Comment: That's what I needed ! Simple and works great ! Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

In Angular you tend to build your template from your model. So you could just declare your link inside your div, and interpolate each error code in the loop.

```html
<div *ngFor="let error of arrayOfErrors">
  my error has this code 
  <b>
    <a [routerLink]="'/#/my-link/' + error.errorCode">{{error.errorCode}}/a>
  </b>.
</div>
```

Comment: The point is that I had a lot of kind of error messages with a lot of different structure ! Your answer is right but in my specific case, the one of @Supercool was the solution of my problem ! Anyway, thanks for your answer !